# Trying to make CSS inline with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know any directions or JavaScript code for making CSS from a stylesheet inline on an HTML?
I’m doing searches, but there’s a conflict with search relevance and what I’m looking for, I believe.

clarifying: the idea is to take css and html as string parameters and mix the inline css. the result should be an html with all the inline css. I wondering if there's not a script for it.

The intent is to generate the HTML output without linked css given both files for an HTML email.

Comment: Do you mean take css from a css file and apply it directly to an element in a style attribute?

Comment: Hi Ruben, can you explain a bit more what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this something that `!important` can't solve?

Comment: css has more than will fit in Element.style, for example a:link, button:hover, div::after, content:, etc. if you discount special sauce, you can loop throught document.styleSheets and iterate the cssRules collection, applying each selectorText to document.querySelectorAll(), then looping through the cssRules and setting each style attrib on the element's style object. even then, you might lose cascading importance, but it might work for your needs...

Answer (score 2):

Are you searching likely to this `object.style.display="inline"`

```
document.getElementById('id').style.width = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking to insert inline CSS.

```
var someitem = document.getElementById('someid');
someitem.setAttribute('style', 'color:#FFF;margin:10px;');
```

The above JS will have the same effects as the following CSS.

```
#someid{color:#FFF;margin:10px;}
```

Comment: It's best to update the `.style` property of the element, rather than set the attribute directly, as it will not override all the existing properties then.